# How to manually move GUI elements?

Tags: java, user-interface

This is a potion of my code:

```
    topPanel = new JPanel ();
    subheading = new JLabel("CRUISES");
    description = new JLabel("Add or remove Cruises or click to assign a Cruise to a ship.");

    topPanel.add(subheading);
    topPanel.add(description);
    CruiseFrame.add(topPanel);
    CruiseFrame.setVisible(true)
```

Everything is working well, and upon running the above, I get the following result in my GUI:

```
"CRUISES Add or remove Cruises or click to assign a Cruise to a ship."
```

However, I wish to have the output as:

```
CRUISES
Add or remove Cruises or click to assign a Cruise to a ship.
```

I wish to have them on seperate lines, how do I go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Read some tutorial that explains how to manage Layouts. Your topPanel has FlowLayout by default, which adds one component next to the other. Try to use GridLayout instead. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize simple HTML in Swing to style JLabels:

```
"<html>CRUISES<br> Add or remove Cruises or click to assign a Cruise to a ship.</html>"
```

Which will look like:

"CRUISES
 Add or remove Cruises or click to assign a Cruise to a ship."

This might be better than using two JLabels, if it does meet the layout requirements.